Get port of subprocess/exec
I have a code that should get either a python or bash script and execute it using exec or subprocess.check_output.
I cannot edit the original code.
The given code should initiate a session (using requests or curl or socket or telnet etc..) and I want to know the local port given to this subprocess running the code during the session.
For example:
In [115]: process = subprocess.Popen(['curl', 'www.example.com'])
     ...: ps = psutil.Process(process.pid)
     ...: print(ps.connections(), ps.net_connections(), ps.open_files())
     ...: print(process.pid)
     ...: process.communicate()

I'd like to know what is the local port created in the session to example.com.
I thought about sniffing packets during the run, but since I'm planning on running concurrent requests it won't help me differentiate between them.
I'm using macOS, but planning to run this code on an ubuntu VM.

You're not going to be able to do this with the subprocess module. You need to use the ptrace(2) system call on Linux to attach to trace the child process. In essence, you want to implement a small part of the strace utility.

Well, you might be able to use the preexec_fn argument to add some ptrace code, but that might be more difficult than if you just implement the fork+exec yourself.

After starting the process you can execute the lsof command. But if it's a bash script, the port will probably have been opened by another program that it runs, so you'll need to use psutil to enumerate all the processes in this hierarchy and check all of their ports.

Can you elaborate on the ptrace solution?
And as for the lsof - I can't guarantee to catch all packets created by the process that way.
